# MongoDB 3.2.1 unrecognized pipeline stage name: $lookup

Tags: mongodb, collections, lookup

I have to "join" 2 collections in MongoDB, my current version is 3.2.1, I saw the lookup pipeline could do what I want but it send me an error message code 16436, exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: $lookup, and I can't find an answer to my issue online, the only post I saw was from people with an anterior version of MongoDB.

Here is my code :

```
db.coursesList.aggregate([{ $lookup: { from: 'companies', localField: 'companyId', foreignField: '_id', as: 'company' } }]);
```

Comment: Sounds like your server isn't actually 3.2.1. What does `db.version()` return in the shell when connected to this server?

Comment: yeah you're right, i messed up something i'll reinstall everything.